# jenkinsfile copyArtifacts fails

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have [Copy Artifact](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) Plugin installed & trying to build and deploy through jenkins pipeline with following Jenkinsfile

Parameter `DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER` default to current build number. I want to make it such a way pipeline should build and deploy if `DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER` is current build number OR just deploy whatever build number specified for `DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER`

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'windows' }

    parameters {
        string(
            name: 'DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER',
            defaultValue: '${BUILD_NUMBER}',
            description: 'Fresh Build and Deploy OR Deploy Previous Build Number'
        )
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "Building"
            }
            post {
                success {
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build.tar.gz', fingerprint: true
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo "Deploying...."
                script {
                    step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
                    projectName: '${JOB_NAME}',
                    filter: "*.tar.gz"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this pipeline I get following error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named CopyArtifact
```

Also tried

```
stage ('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo "Deploying...."
            copyArtifacts filter: '*.tar.gz', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: '${JOB_NAME}'
        }
    }
```

which failed with following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'copyArtifacts' found among steps
```

and

```
stage ('Deploy') {
    steps {
        echo "Deploying...."
        script {
                copyArtifacts filter: '*.tar.gz', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: '${JOB_NAME}'
            }
    }
}
```

which gave me

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'copyArtifacts' found among steps
```

What is the correct syntax for copyArtifacts ? what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 4):

I would check the version of the Copy Artifacts plugin you have installed (you can see that in /pluginManager/installed), the minimum version that supports pipeline is 1.39

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it with "script { .. }"

```
        post {
          success {
            script {
              archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build.tar.gz', fingerprint: true
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

CopyArtifact defines a step, copyArtifacts, that you can use directly.

Check the step reference [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/)

Comment: Adding just a link to the documentation does not answer to the question at all. Looking at the work put on the question, the author of the question already knows there is a documentation. The question does not ask for a documentation link, it asks for the correct syntax of using the plugin.

Comment: Hi @TurgutSarıçam, if you look carefully at the date of the original post and my response, you'll notice that his post has been updated since my response.  My response was to have him use the step directly not the class and method version he started with.